# Detect when an element is in the viewport using GSAP ScrollTrigger Plugin

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am trying to detect when an element is in the viewport using GSAP3's Scroll Trigger Pluging. However, it doesn't seem to want to work. The terminal is reporting:

```
"Invalid property" "scrollTrigger" "set to" Object {
  trigger: ".c"
} "Missing plugin? gsap.registerPlugin()"
```

My JS code is as below:

```
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
gsap.to(".box", {
    scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".c"
    },
    x: 400,
    rotation: 360
});
```

Then the HTML is:

```
<section>
  EMPTY
</section>

<section>
  <div class="box c">
    HELLO
  </div>
</section>
```

I also came across someone who had a similar issue https://greensock.com/forums/topic/24472-invalid-property-scrolltrigger/ However, even trying solutions from the GreenSock Docs it still doesn't work.

Comment: Hey Al-76. This just means that ScrollTrigger is failing to load before your script is running. If you check the console or resources panel in your developer tools I'm betting it'll tell you that. If not, it's possibly a load order issue (you're running your custom JS before ScrollTrigger was loaded). Or perhaps you're trying to load the modules version of the plugin whereas you should be using the minified version. Without seeing more of your setup it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: Thanks @Zach You were right. It was version of the of the plugin which was too old to support what I was trying. I have updated it and it now works. Thanks for helping. Much appreciated.